# I am redirecting to login page while using the local storage in laravel with chrome extension (Content.js)

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to see if the user is logged in to current web browsers so I want to check the user token with id so that the chrome extension starts working.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://factstart.herokuapp.com/api",
            type: 'GET',
            // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            // Fetch the stored token from localStorage and set in the header
            headers: {
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('data'),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            success: function(token) {
                    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(token);
                    console.log(data);
                    var id = data.id;
            },
});
```

So I am using the laravel package spectrum to generate the web tokens[in chrome dev it works find get token and id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPcWB.png)

But when I run in the actual site it throws me `VM9360:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` this error and it is an unlogged page so how to overcome this problem?

This is the  PHP code to access the token

```
     public function token(Request $request) {
        
              if (Auth::user()) {
                $data = array();
            // $user = request()->user();
            $data['id'] = request()->user()->id;
            $data['token'] = request()->user()->tokens()->where('tokenable_id', $data['id'])->get('token')
            ->first()->token;
            return json_encode((array) $data);

    } else {
        return "Login to get data";
    }
}
```

// Extra details added for clarity

When I run the code like a refresh in the extension the token gets auth. At the same instance when I refresh in web tab it will take me to the login screen. And the js code I have written in content.js. So that I will first check if the user is logged in then the chrome extension should start working.

Comment: I think it's your JSON data that is aligned with JSON format. Please recheck it.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi Hello, I have changed to json formate like this
{"id":1,"token":"45ebcdc4fe01ee70111b327c07be5133d79bbc710b24fb06f85ab65368b7f56e"}
But I am on the same issue it redirecting me to the login screen

Answer (score 0):

Set your authorization as `Bearer ${token}`
And use `auth('sanctum')->user()` instead of `Auth::user()`

Comment: I have tried your answer. I will get the id and token in the chrome background console like the image I have attached above. But when I refresh the tab and see the token and Id I takes me to the login page!